# Adding external javascript in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, netbeans

I want to insert an external javascript file in my JSF page. So what I did is:

Now, the JSF file is named start.xhtml and both are sitting in the same folder. However, when I ran , there is nothing happend [ The javascript supposed to pop up alert when I click]. I checked the page source, and apparent in the .

What did I do wrong to get the RES NOT FOUND? I even put absolute path but nothing happened :(. Me sad panda.

Fyi, I am using the latest Netbeans.

Thanks,
Song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, an absolute path must work. It's not question of Netbeans or Glassfih, or JSF - it's a browser thing. And if your browser had a fault preventing it from fetching Javascript from valid urls, you would have noticed. So if your Javascript does not load, there's a 99% chance it's a plain typo, a stupid mistake (forgetting directory name, adding an extra slash or such things), and nothing to do with any of the mentioned technologies.

The other theory (just a theory - I don't have enough data to prove it) is that you have a standard mapping, showing all the faces files in a "virtual" faces directory (*/faces/**). So that when you put your index.xhtml in the main directory of a Foo project, you see it under: *localhost:8080/Foo/faces/index.xhtml*. The "faces" part of path does not represent any real directory, it's just a mapping. So if you have a js file sitting by an index.xhtml, you would address it like: *'../yourjavascript.js'*; the *../* is to compensate for the virtual directory part.

Anyway, I strongly encourage you to drop your script loading dillemas and use the official and nice way of loading resources such as javascript is to put them into a directory called "resources" (make one under the "web pages" node in Netbeans, it will end up in the top directory of your .war); to get a path of any file saved under resources, you use EL like: #{resource['filename.css']}. You will load your script by:

```
   <script src='#{resource['script.js']}' ></script>
```

If you use the resource directory, you can do many more things, [read up on some detailshere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu1/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try including your script this way

```
<script src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/yourPathAfterWebpages/scriptFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Simple, clear and working!